# Unix - How to replace invalid characters?

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I a writing unix bash shell script.

I want to replace all invalid characters in a text with underscore("_").
My valid characters list is  a-z, A-Z, "_" and 0-9. Basically it is alphanumeric and _.
In the below example

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=soa.ax-123
```

I want the variable hostname value to be replaced as soa_ax_123

Can anyone help me to write the login to find and replace the invalid characters with "_"

Thanks in advance
chris

Comment: `sed` is your friend.

Comment: Seems like a perfect job for 'tr'.   tr is your friend. `tr -c '[[:alnum:]_]' _`.

Answer (score 10):

You can do pattern substitution in parameter expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=soa.ax-123
newhostname=${hostname//[^a-zA-Z_0-9]/_}
echo "The fixed hostname is $newhostname"
```

Comment: more examples of [search and replace](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace)

Comment: You can also use the predefined `word` character class: `newhostname=${hostname//[^[:word:]]/_}`

Comment: @chepner in that case you'd have to set the locale to C first

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
echo $hostname | sed 's/\W/_/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hostname=$(echo soa.ax-123 | sed s/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/_/g)
```